# How to disable Docker container to restart for `gcloud preview app run`

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, docker, boot2docker, gcloud-node

I start my Nodejs app with `gcloud preview app run .` command.

Every time I update any file inside the project, `gcloud` restarts Docker container. It always takes a lot of time.

In [Google Compute Engine Docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#container_manifest) I have found `restartPolicy` configuration, but trying to add it into my `app.yaml`, throws an error when running the app:

> ERROR: Configuration is not valid: Unexpected attribute 'restartPolicy' for object of type AppInfoExternal.

*What probably means it isn't supposed to work with custom VMs on Google Cloud.*

I am wondering if there's a way to tell `gcloud` to disable automatic Docker container restart, but make it somehow manually when I need it?